# get data from a unique php file

Tags: php, ajax

I am developing a web app and as usual I write lots of php file in order to support my ajax call.

I was wondering if there is any way to write a unique php file and get data from this unique file.

For example if I write lot of functions into my php file I cant get data from a specific function I wondering.

Comment: so what!!! you need a file which handles all right?

Comment: Post some code of urs to enlighten us about ur problem

Comment: I would prefer you to go with @Ioannis Karadimas answer

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. It 's a matter of designing your file to work with parameters for different calls. A very simple example:

```
<?php
    function action1() {}

    function default_action() {}

    var action = isset($_POST['action']) && (strlen($_POST['action']) > 0)
        ? $_POST['action']
        : '';

    switch(action) {
        case "action1": 
            action1();
            break;
        default: 
            default_action();
            break;
    }
?>
```

Having a similar file, you can then call methods in it using a hidden action field. To call `action1`, you would use something like this in your ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "thephpfile.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: { action: "action1" }
    ...
});
```